# Why axios.patch doesn't change data in ToDoList?

Tags: javascript, axios

Roughly speaking, I have a ToDoList in which I want to change the written task text. But on demand to find an error. The data from the input that enters the changed text is stored in the state (editingText), with this text I'm trying to replace the value in the 'text' column. Does anyone know what could be the problem I'm missing?

```
 const submitEdits = (item) => {
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:3004/item/${item.id}`, { text: editingText }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    setIdItem(null);
    setEditingText('')
}
```

My db.json

```
    {
     "item": [
         {
  "text": "Пошел в свой первый класс",
  "id": 0,
  "data": {
    "year": 2012,
    "day": 25,
    "month": 1
  }
},
{
  "text": "Поступил в институт",
  "id": 1,
  "data": {
    "year": 2007,
    "day": 12,
    "month": 4
  }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "text": "123",
  "data": {
    "year": 123,
    "day": 12,
    "month": 12
           }
         }
       ]
      }
```

[image]

Comment: What server do you use?

Comment: Its json-server, sir

Comment: Is it listening on port 3004? Don't post images of code, error messages and logs. The error message doesn't fit the code. The code contains `http://localhost:3004/item` but the error message `http://localhost/item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the request itself.
It was written about 3004 port listening.
But the request sends to

```js
http://localhost/...
```

It is without port.
Ut has to be like this i guess:

```js
http://localhost:3004/...
```

Comment: `ERROR_CONNREFUSED` error throws when you send request to invalid address (adress is not a server or server not exists). so pls check the request sending error logs and sending code twice

Comment: What are the requests in `Nework` tab are showing? Are they with the port?

Comment: sorry, that's my mistake.... Oh my god, you'll be right. Such a stupid mistake